# Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'X' and 'X'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

I'm using `Entity Framework` and here it's my entity Model:

```
Public class Document
{
    Public int Id { get; set; }
    Public Document Parent { get; set; }
}
```

and as you see that it has a `self-reference` property.

Now I'm trying to add another `self-reference` property like this:

```
Public class Document
{
    Public int Id { get; set; }
    Public Document Parent { get; set; }
    Public Document SrcDocument { get; set; }
}
```

But unfortunately I've faced with below error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Document' and 'Document'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: Do you want to make a one-to-many relation with that?

Comment: some how yeah but it's doesn't work?

Comment: do write any code to define these relations?

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: The error is telling you that you must use the Fluent API to configure your relationships between the objects.  Which is what Majid is eluding to.

Comment: Here is a similar scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927415/unable-to-determine-the-principal-end-of-an-association-between-the-types-enti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework `Code-First` conventions are assuming that `Document` and `Document` belong to the same relationship and are the inverse navigation properties of each other. Because both navigation properties are references (not collections) `EF` infers a `one-to-one` relationship.

Since you actually want two `one-to-many` relationships you must override the conventions. Just override `OnModelCreating` method of the context and put there what's your idea about new cycle-relation like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasRequired(p => p.SrcDocument).WithMany();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

## Update

`modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasRequired(p => p.SrcDocument).WithMany();` say to Entity Framework the `SrcDocument` has a `one-to-many` relation with itself.

and also you can use below code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasOptional(p => p.SrcDocument).WithMany();
```

to make a `zero-to-many` relation.

and with this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasOptional(p => p.SrcDocument).WithOptionalDependent();
```

you can define a `one-to-zero` relation.

It'll be worked.

Comment: "Since you actually want two one-to-many" this is not what I'm reading in the question. Also, your code piece does define one of the properties as the navigation property in a one-to-zero or one relationship. You should streamline those assertions, since then the answer will likely be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `InverseProperty` attribute:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Document Parent { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Document SrcDocument { get; set; }
    public int SrcDocumentId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Children {get;set;}
    [InverseProperty("SrcDocument")]
    public virtual ICollection<Document> Derived {get;set;}
}
```

**Migration:**

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Documents",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            ParentId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            SrcDocumentId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Documents", t => t.ParentId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Documents", t => t.SrcDocumentId)
    .Index(t => t.ParentId)
    .Index(t => t.SrcDocumentId);
```